# C++ inherited method not seen from within derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have been playing around with C++'s inheritance, checking which methods are overridden and which get called in different situations. I ended up with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>


class EmptyA {}; 
class DerEmptyA : public EmptyA {}; 
class DerDerEmptyA : public DerEmptyA {}; 

class Base
{
public:
        void f(EmptyA)
        {
                std::cout << "Base::f(EmptyA)\n";
        }

        void f(DerEmptyA)
        {
                std::cout << "Base::f(DerEmptyA)\n";
        }

        virtual void handle(EmptyA ea) 
        {
                std::cout << "Base::handle(EmptyA) - ";
                f(ea);
        }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
        void f(DerDerEmptyA)
        {
                std::cout << "Derived::f(DerDerEmptyA)\n";
        }

        virtual void handle(EmptyA ea) override final
        {
                std::cout << "Derived::handle(EmptyA) - ";
                f(ea);
        }
};


int main()
{
        Derived d;
        d.handle(EmptyA{});
        d.handle(DerDerEmptyA{});
}
```

I expected the first call to `handle` from main (that is `d.handle(EmptyA{})`) to be forwarded to `Base::f(EmptyA)`, however, on my `g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0` this results in a compilation error:

```
tmp.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Derived::handle(EmptyA)’:
tmp.cpp:39:5: error: cannot convert ‘EmptyA’ to ‘DerDerEmptyA’
   39 |   f(ea);
      |     ^~
      |     |
      |     EmptyA
tmp.cpp:31:9: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void Derived::f(DerDerEmptyA)’
   31 |  void f(DerDerEmptyA)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Note: replacing the line `f(ea);` with `Base::f(ea);` in the `Derived::handle` function does not seem like a correct solution because in that case the next call from main (that is `d.handle(DerDerEmptyA{})`) will be forwarded to `Base::f(EmptyA)` instead of `Derived::f(DerDerEmptyA)`.

So, I have two questions:

1. Why did `Base::f(EmptyA)` become inaccessible from `Derived::handle`?
2. How can I fix this code so that every call to `Derived::handle` is forwarded to the most specific version of method `f`?

Answer (score 2):

To **solve this** (that is, if you want the Base version of `f`), you can use:

```
Base::f(ea);
```

For calling/using the `Base` version.

The **problem is** when you use just `f(ea);` the Derived version of `f` is selected since the search starts from `Derived` class and stops when it founds `f`.

The program works if you use `Base::f(ea);` as can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/GDk0P51IH).

**Edit**

Now seeing your edited question and the comment below, i think you have missed one thing which is

> the `handle()` function inside the Derived class takes parameter of type `EmptyA` only and there is no version of handle() inside the Derived class that takes parameter of type `DerDerEmptyA` . So both of your calls to handle() will call the same `Base::f` that takes `EmptyA` as argument.

If you want the specific version called then you have to provide one as i did in my modified example below which have your desired output/result:

```
#include <iostream>


class EmptyA {}; 
class DerEmptyA : public EmptyA {}; 
class DerDerEmptyA : public DerEmptyA {}; 

class Base
{
public:
        void f(EmptyA)
        {
                std::cout << "Base::f(EmptyA)\n";
        }

        void f(DerEmptyA)
        {
                std::cout << "Base::f(DerEmptyA)\n";
        }
        //added this
        void f(DerDerEmptyA)
        {
                std::cout << "Base::f(DerDerEmptyA)\n";
        }
        
        virtual void handle(EmptyA ea) 
        {
                std::cout << "Base::handle(EmptyA) - ";
                f(ea);
        }
        //added this
        virtual void handle(DerDerEmptyA ea) 
        {
                std::cout << "Base::handle(DerDerEmptyA) - ";
                f(ea);
        }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
        void f(DerDerEmptyA)
        {
                std::cout << "Derived::f(DerDerEmptyA)\n";
        }

        virtual void handle(EmptyA ea) override final
        {
                std::cout << "Derived::handle(EmptyA) - ";
                Base::f(ea);
                
        }
        //added this 
        virtual void handle(DerDerEmptyA ea) override final
        {
                std::cout << "Derived::handle(DerDerEmptyA) - ";
                Base::f(ea);
                
        }
};


int main()
{
        Derived d;
        d.handle(EmptyA{});
        d.handle(DerDerEmptyA{});
}
```

Also take notice of the **implicit conversions** that may be happening(if any).

Comment: Yes, I thought of such a solution, but no, it does not seem correct to me: for the second call (that is `d.handle(DerDerEmptyA{})`) your code sample forwards the call to `Base::f(EmptyA)`, but I want it to be forwarded to `Derived::f(DerDerEmpty)`. In general, I want every call to `handle` to be forwarded to the most specific method (sorry for not mentioning it previously, I have now updated the question)

Comment: @Kolay.Ne If you want the specific version called then you have to provide one as i did in my edited answer. Check it out. I have added comments in the code where i have added the functions. Check out the edit part of my answer.

Comment: I see. Well, it is obvious that it will work if you add functions for each type. But I thought it could be achieved with automatic dynamic types analysis on the compiler's side. However, after playing around a bit more I figured out that when a call `f(ea)` is made, it is forwarded to `f(EmptyA)` regardless of the dynamic type of `ea`

Comment: @Kolay.Ne This is because there is an implicit conversion from a derived class to a base class. If you see your original version of the question(code) then the second call to `handle()` had this implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Bring `Base::f` into `Derived`'s scope:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::f;

    //...
};
```

Comment: 1. Thank you, the compile error disappeared. Why does this not happen by default when I inherit a class? Where can I read more about scoping rules of inheritance in C++?
2. Unfortunately, it still does not produce the expected result: both calls to `handle` get forwarded to `Base::f(EmptyA)` (which surprises me because I thought the compiler is supposed to select the most specific method in such a situation)

Comment: @Kolay.Ne 1. Because the standard says so. I don't know what the rationale is. Relevant name lookup rules are explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) 2. Both `handle` functions call `f` with an argument of type `EmptyA`, why do you expect this to resolve to anything other than `Base::f(EmptyA)`?

Comment: 1. Thank you for the link, this is what I was looking for. 2. I expected C++ to resolve the call according to the dynamic type of the argument, but have already figured out this is not the case